# The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>?'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

Due to Recent Update I am facing this problem Please Guys Help me out

[image: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider?'.]

```
 late PickedFile _imageFile1, _imageFile2;
 final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();


CircleAvatar(
      radius: 80.0,
      backgroundImage: _imageFile2 == null
          ? AssetImage("images/default.jpg")
          : FileImage(File(_imageFile2.path)),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Try this, it will work.***

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 80.0,
  child: _imageFile2 == null
      ? Image.asset("images/default.jpg")
      : Image.file(File(_imageFile2.path)),
),
```

Comment: This is the same as previous answer.

Comment: See here *Image.asset* and *Image.file* instead of AssetImage and FileImage, It's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `child` property instead of `backgroundImage`:

```
CircleAvatar(
      radius: 80.0,
      child: _imageFile2 == null
          ? AssetImage("images/default.jpg")
          : FileImage(File(_imageFile2.path),
      ),
),
```

Comment: i tried but there was same problem bro 
The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'.

Comment: I just tried it and I didn't get any errors. Maybe the error is because of something else?